# Remove array item by index (not numeric index but string)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following JavaScript array :

```
[#ad: Array[0]]
    #ad: Array[0]
        #image_upload: Array[0]
            13b7afb8b11644e17569bd2efb571b10: "This is an error"
            69553926a7783c27f7c18eff55cbd429: "Yet another error"
            d3042d83b81e01d5c2b8bbe507f0d709: "Another error"
    Array[0]
        #image_url: Array[0]
            2b4a9847e26368312704b8849de9247a: "URL error"
```

This is the array representation in my browser console.

Unfortunatelly I cannot find a way to remove the elements of the `$errors['#ad']['#image_upload']` based on the `md5` keys.

In example, let's say I like to remove the message `"Yet another error"` by using the corresponding md5 key `69553926a7783c27f7c18eff55cbd429`.

I have try the method `indexOf` but this is not the correct one, as return the index of the value in the array. What I need is the opposite, I need to remove the value directly by using the index of the value.

How can I perform this task ? Any idea ?

Comment: I very much doubt that `indexOf` works at all here, because the properties you listed are not considered to be elements of the array. You should use plain objects if you work with non-numeric keys, not arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `delete` operator should work here:

```
delete $errors['#ad']['#image_upload']['69553926a7783c27f7c18eff55cbd429']
```

Comment: Is that so simple ? Let me try it ... !! Thansk for your response.

Comment: Yes, was that simple !! Thanks a lot . . . I will mark your answer as the correct answer in about 11 minutes